# Select multiple elements with predicates

Tags: html, xpath

I want to select multiple elements (knowing there indexes) with predicates in xPath.

say I have this HTML file:

```
<body>
    <table>
        <tr> <!-- tr 1 -->
            <td>element 1.1</td>
            <td>element 1.2</td>
        </tr>

        <tr> <!-- tr 2 -->
            <td>element 2.1</td>
            <td>element 2.2</td>
        </tr>

        <tr> <!-- tr 3 -->
            <td>element 3.1</td>
            <td>element 3.2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

I use : `//table/tr[3]/td[2]` to select the 2nd `td` of the 3rd `tr`.

what about selecting the 2nd `td` of the 1st AND 3rd `tr` at once (with one xPath) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `or` to combine both `position()=1` and `position()=3` to find both the 1st and 3rd `tr` elements:

```
//table/tr[position()=1 or position()=3]/td[2]
```

Note that you can't use `tr[1 or 3]` because all that does is evaluate `1` and `3` as Boolean values, resulting in a match for every `tr` because `1 or 3` is `true or true` is always `true`.

Comment: @Ghilas BELHADJ: Sorry, I must have read that one wrong. Edited.